# Grouping in DataGrid bound to a *sample* data source (using Silverlight “Data” window)

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, grouping, blend

Silverlight 5 question. I can group items in a DataGrid by using PagedCollectionView as its ItemsSource (via GroupDescriptions.Add). No problem. However, we are designers (not experienced programmers) working on a prototype and are using the Blend “Data” window extensively where we can conveniently create sample data sources / collections and sample enter data. Unfortunately, GroupDescriptions.Add doesn’t seem to work on these xml-based collections created through the “Data” window.

Is there a way to use grouping in DataGrid without having to use C#? Or is there a way to group the sample data created through the “Data” window in a DataGrid?

I did my research and I'm starting to think this may not be possible. My first post, go easy on me! Thanks -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to view Silverlight Datagrid group in designer (blend or VS) :

You can try to create a XAML `CollectionViewSource` bind to a sample data Collection :

1. Create a new sample data named "customerSampleData" ;
2. Add a collection property (named "Collection") with 2 sub properties (Name, Age) ;
3. Add the `CollectionViewSource` in resources with `PropertyGroupDescription`.

See the last step :

```xml
xmlns:compMod="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=System.Windows"
xmlns:SampleData="clr-namespace:Expression.Blend.SampleData.customerSampleData"
...
</UserControl.Resources>
    <SampleData:customerSampleData x:Key="customerSampleData" d:IsDataSource="True"/>

    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Key="dataSource"
        d:IsDataSource="True"
        Source="{Binding Collection, Source={StaticResource customerSampleData}}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <compMod:SortDescription PropertyName="Name" Direction="Ascending"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Age"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" DataContext="">
    <sdk:DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataSource}}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name"/>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Age}" Header="Age"/>
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </sdk:DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: <3 Blend ;) It is true that it is easier when you see in designer what you are doing. Good luck !

Comment: Yes, especially for designers like us. It is really neat to see that you can tweak the xaml (e.g., change grouping field) and it instantly repaints the artboard! Neat :- )

Comment: Blend and the MVVM pattern is really great for a team like yours. it allows a well distributed work. Thank you a guy who designed the binding and XAML ;)